# del *a: can't use starred expression here

Tags: python, parsing, language-lawyer, grammar, del

The [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) for del statement:

```
del_stmt: 'del' (expr|star_expr) (',' (expr|star_expr))* [',']
```

It allows deleting starred expressions. So, the parser doesn't mind this, even though it would be causing `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here` at runtime:

```
>>> ast.parse("del *a")
<_ast.Module at 0xcafef00d>
>>> ast.dump(compile('del *a', filename='wtf.py', mode='single', flags=ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST))
"Interactive(body=[Delete(targets=[Starred(value=Name(id='a', ctx=Del()), ctx=Del())])])"
```

Is there some usage I'm missing which can have a starred delete target? Shouldn't it be instead the simpler grammar:

```
del_stmt: 'del' expr (',' expr)* [',']
```

Why does the grammar allow for deleting starred expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual grammar is defined in terms of `exprlist`; it looks like [that association dates back to before 3.0](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/grammar.html), when `star_expr` became a thing; previously, it was `expr` exclusively.

Basically, the grammar allows it because they added a new feature to `exprlist`, and didn't go to the trouble of making it illegal by the grammar in all the cases where `star_expr` doesn't actually make sense, they just made the compiler reject nonsensical cases at a later stage.

It's hacky, but it works, and I assume either helps simplify the parser, and/or it's just too much trouble to define and implement separate concepts for `exprlist` vs. `maybe_star_exprlist`.